# How is uint overflow defined in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, integer-overflow

What happens when the result of a multiplication or sum in OpenCL overflows? Does it wrap?

In particular I'd like to know if I can catch an overflow in

`uint4 x = ( get_global_id( 0 ) * 4 + (uint4)(0, 1, 2, 3) ) * q + r;`

with

`int4 invalid = x < get_global_id( 0 ) * 4;`

or how else that would be possible. (Assuming `r >= 0 && q > r && q < (1 << 20)` and the id will be at most just big enough to cause an overflow.)

Context: I want to check every 32 bit uint `x` for which `x % q == r` , where `q` and `r` are known. With vectors I can check 4 at a time, but the number of tests may not be divisible by 4.

I'm targeting the GPU, but that shouldn't be relevant, right?

Comment: As far as I know and tested, OpenCL overflows silently. That is not a problem. But if you are going to check the overflow later on, is better not to let it overflow in the first place. Use ulong values and then trucate them to uint is a better choise, and is a cheap operation. GPU and CPU will be exactly the same in this case, since is an integer operation.

Comment: Thanks, using a ulong is a pretty obvious solution in retrospect. If it's cheap I might as well do that and be safe.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCL 1.2 standard](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf#page=212) (section 6.2.3.3) refers to C99 standard (section 6.3.1.3):

> ...if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
> subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
> until the value is in the range of the new type.

Generally, get_global_id returns size_t, so narrowing conversion is bad idea IMO. Though, I never faced NDRange big enough to exceed uint range.